# How to remove mainwindow titlebar permanently?

Tags: c++, qt5, qmainwindow

When I set mainwindow to fullscreen() , title bar disappears, thats what I want. But when a dialog is opened main window title bar appears again, which is undesirable in my case.I have tried setting several Qt::windowflags but they dont work.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If one window is full screen then no other window can come on top of it. Since a dialog forces its way to the top, the original window loses its fullscreen status.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer here, you have to do something like this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  MyMainWindow window;
  window.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
  window.show();
}
```

**PS**: What I gather from the net is that, the results are a bit ambiguous. Do let us know the result

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It just shrink my app window. Nothing else.

Comment: Can something be done with QDialog instead of messing with mainwindow? because it is working fine without the Dialog.

Comment: I want to pop up a numeric keypad through this. Is there any other workaround for this?

Comment: Can you include a image of the current state in your question? It would be helpful to understand. Plus, did you `setWindowsFlags()` at the very start like in this answer? or did you set it later?

Comment: I set up the flags in main.cpp like above.Now I have managed to remove title bar when dialog appears by adding one more flag to dialog.setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint|Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint|Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

Comment: But the dialog appears in top left corner, I want it to be in centre.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I cannot be anymore help here

Answer (score 0):

To move the dialog in the centre:
1.Calling widget should pass the centre co-ordinates to the dialog window.
  I have done it by passing co-ordinates by calling a dialog funuction.
  In widget.cpp:

```
dialog->centre(this->width()/2,this->height()/2);
```

2.In the dialog.cpp :

```
`centre(int x,int y)
{
    width =x;     //store in some global variable
    height=y;
}`
```

3.In the show event of dialog.cpp:

```
this->move(width,height);
```

Done. It will place the dialog in the centre of the widget.